# SDL2 Install problems: makefile.win file not recognized: file format not recognized and collect2.exe [error] id return1 exit status

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, mingw, sdl-2

After I learned the very basics of cpp i decided to push myself ahead and try SDL2 and try to make a game. I found the lazy foo's SDL tutorials. I tried to follow it but i seemed to have problems with installation. After putting in a "test" code i tried compiling it, and these messages showed up on the log:

C:\File\Location\For\My\Project\Makefile.win    file not recognized: File format not recognized
C:\File\Location\For\My\Project\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

I think it might be a linking error and heres my linkers:-lmingw32-lSDL2main-lSDL2
I tried deleting this Makefile.win but the same message just showed up and there isn't even a collect2.exe

I'm using the Orwell Dev-C++ using the mingw gcc 4.8.1 32bit release compiler, and heres the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) != 0){
        std::cout << "SDL_Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I assume Makefile.win is a Dev-C++ generated file. Are you able to show it (put a copy in pastebin or other similar site)

Comment: oh i figure out the problem, i used the x64 version of SDL for this and my compiler is a x32 compiler, and i looked up makefile.win and people said its a dev-c++ generated file.